# Combining Files & header from 3rd file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to copy 2 text files from a folder & from the same folder copy first line of another text file add as header to new output file.

copy file1.txt+file2.txt+copy first line from file3.txt | out-file combinedfiles.txt

Is there a one liner solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
(gc file3.txt)[0] + (gc file1.txt) + (gc file2.txt) | out-file combinedfiles.txt
```